# ArcGIS Convert IGeometryCollection to IEnumGeometry

Tags: c#, arcobjects

I have a group of polylines mistakenly created with a geometry for each vertex pair. Typically they have thousands of geometries.
I would like to merge the geometries (note: NOT merge features) in each feature into one geometry. To do this I am using **ITopologicalOperator5.ConstructUnion**. ConstructUnion takes an IEnumGeometry parameter and I have an IGeometryCollection of geometries. I can create an IEnumGeometry using a GeometryBag but ConstructUnion does not accept GeometryBags.
If I use IEnumGeometry pEnum = (IEnumGeometry)pGeomCollection it throws an exception.
If I use IEnumGeometry pEnum = pGeomCollection as IEnumGeometry then pEnum is null.
In VB.NET Ctype(pGeomCollection, IEnumGeometry) works fine.
Can anyone tell me how to convert a (C#) Geometry Collection into an IEnumGeometry?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to link the Geometry Bag and the Geometry Collection when they are initiated:

```
IGeometryBag pGeomBag = new GeometryBagClass();
pGeomBag.SpatialReference = .......

IGeometryCollection pGeomColl = new PolylineClass();
pGeomColl = (IGeometryCollection)pGeomBag;

IEnumGeometry pEnum = new EnumFeatureGeometryClass();
pEnum = (IEnumGeometry)pGeomBag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
IEnumGeometry enumGeom = (IEnumGeometry)((IGeometryBag)geometryCollection);
```

IGeometryBag implements IGeometryCollection, and IGeometryBag implements IEnumGeometry.

But GeometryCollection doesn't implement IEnumGeometry directly, so you'll have to cast it to GeometryBag first, and afterwards to IEnumGeometry.

Comment: Thanks Gwen. Unfortunately it didn't work. It crashes with the error: 'Unable to cast COM object of type PolylineClass to interface type IGeometryBag'.

Comment: Have you initialized your polyline object as IPolyLine? Like: IPolyLine pl = new PolyLineClass(); The class object of PolyLine doesn't implement IGeometryBag, but the interface does.